# HTML tables in JTextPane showing weird "form" boxes

Tags: java, html, html-table, jtextpane

I'm trying to put an html table in an editable JTextPane. So you can edit tables in it like an excel sheet. When I try to do it, these weird col and colgroup boxes keep showing up. Also, the table doesn't seem to work like they're supposed to..

Here's an example:

[image]

```
            import java.awt.BorderLayout;
            import java.awt.EventQueue;
            import javax.swing.JFrame;
            import javax.swing.JPanel;
            import javax.swing.JTextPane;
            import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
            import javax.swing.text.Document;
            import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
            import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

            public class htmlEditor2 extends JFrame {
                private JPanel contentPane;
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                htmlEditor2 frame = new htmlEditor2();
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                public htmlEditor2() {
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
                    contentPane = new JPanel();
                    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                    setContentPane(contentPane);
                    Foo f = new Foo();
                    f.setText("<html><body><table border=\"1\" width=\"985\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; border-width: 0px; border-color: #010101; \"><colgroup><col width=\"328\"></col>        <col width=\"328\"></col>        <col width=\"328\"></col>    </colgroup><tr><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><font face=\"Arial\"><span style=\"font-size:8pt\">row 1</span></font></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><font face=\"Arial\"><span style=\"font-size:8pt\">row2</span></font></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><font face=\"Arial\"><span style=\"font-size:8pt\">row3</span></font></div></td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td></tr><tr><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td><td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" width=\"321\" style=\"border: solid #010101 1px; \"><div align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-size: 8pt;\">&nbsp;</span></div></td></tr></table><div align=\"left\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></body></html>");
                    contentPane.add(f);
                }
                class Foo extends JTextPane {
                    public Foo() {
                        super();
                        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
                        setEditorKit(kit);
                        StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
                        styleSheet.addRule(""); //in case I need to add a CSS
                        Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
                        setDocument(doc);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I would paste a nicely formatted version of the html, but I'm not sure how to do it on here...

So yeah.. I just want to know how to get rid of those weird colgroup and col boxes in my table and how to make the table work normally!

**UPDATE: So it turns out that the service that I'm retrieving the html tables from autoformats the html table to include the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags. So I have some follow up questions: Does JTextPane support current html versions?  And of course, How do I get the JTextPane to not display those weird boxes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to just use a String.replaceAll() and removed everything I didn't want. I know it seems weird.. buuut. for now. That's my solution. Thanks Reimeus for your answer. I will have to look into your solution when I have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

`JTextPane` only supports markup of HTML 3.2 so newer tags will not appear as they would in the latest browsers.

Rather than attempting to modify the HTML you could use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library such as **[Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp)** to display the content:

```
HtmlPanel panel = new HtmlPanel();
new SimpleHtmlRendererContext(panel, new SimpleUserAgentContext()).navigate("http://myhost/mytable.jsp");
```

Comment: You're a genius. I took out the <col> and <colgroup> tags and its all good. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I updated the question. It turns out that the service that I'm retrieving html from automatically reformats the html code to include the <colgroup> and <col> tags for tables. So the problem still persists... :(

Comment: If you can point at a URL, you could use the solution I have given above.